# Can't reactivate @hostlistener keydown event on an Angular Component after a focusout propagation from child input

Tags: angular, dom, event-propagation

For this particular problem, a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jr1aw3) should be more straightforward.

It represents a simplified version of a real Angular 2+ app problem I have on a `TableComponent` that reacts on `@HostListener('keydown')` for handling keyboard navigation into its cells. Problem is that some cells are editable and displays an `<input>` within their content, focusing in AND out this `<input>` makes the `TableComponent` loose its focus and therefore no more `keydown` events are captured on the table level.

How would you fix that particular problem ?

My attemps for now :

- `window:keydown` is a workaround but isn't a good solution beacause it brings more problems than it solves.
- On input focusout, stopPropagation of the event and trigger focus programmatically on component, but keydown events aren't restored for table anyway